# Bruiser's Phone Call

Tags: bruiser-book

In the book *[Bruiser](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1931915.Bruiser)*, the main character (Brewster) almost dies but then is in a coma. At the final part of the book, all of the phones in the house of the two supporting characters started ringing. How is this possible?

Comment: it's definitely sci-fi... Brewster is described as an empath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explanation given. Much like Brewster's ability to take on the pain of others is never truly explained, so too the phones ringing is an unexplained miracle. As readers, we don't even get the details other than that it happened after Tennyson, Brontë, Cody, and the parents had finally accepted back all of the pain that Bruiser had been holding for them and that it likely signaled Brewster recovering from the coma.

I did pass the question on to the author and this was his response:

> Thanks for your e-mail!  I’m glad that you’re enjoying my books! The ending of Bruiser is purposefully ambiguous It's up to the reader to decide what happened!

He also had under FAQ Answers in the email:

> **Yes** – there IS an answer to whether or not Bruiser wakes up at the end.  It’s right there in the book — you have to reread those last few chapters, and read a little bit between the lines.  In this world we’re used to being spoon-fed answers.  I think you’re smarter than that, and can figure stuff out for yourselves!

I don't know if that helps at all, but I figured I'd pass it on.

Comment: "Read it and you'll know" - you gotta love how the author is providing a NaA :D